# AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url' , discord

Tags: discord.py, bots

Getting 'user.avatar_url' error from the below code sample

[image]

`embed1.set_thumbnail(url = user.avatar_url)`

**AttributeError**: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'

I have no idea why the 'user.avatar_url' is working on my computer but doesn't work on replit.com

Anyone, pls help me......><

Answer (score 1):

You're on an old `discord.py` version, `avatar_url` was removed in 2.0. Always make sure you've got the same version on every environment (which is what things like `requirements` files are for).

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html

> Member.avatar_url (replaced by [Member.avatar](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.avatar))

Also - you shouldn't use sites like replit to host a bot.